# Db field types and C# field types?

Tags: c#, .net, orm, types, ado.net

lets say I have a SP in SQL :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mySP
    @LastName nvarchar(10), 
    @FirstName nvarchar(20) 
AS 
  ...
GO
```

In c# there isn't string type with specified length. its max length is `2^32-1 ( IMHO)`

So , What kind of *protection* does the C# developer has for : **not** to send string with exceeding length ?

*( I don't think any ORM also has this restriction - maybe i'm wrong).*

The only way (I see )  is to read the Sp params before(!) and keep in cache  , and then to build some kind of proxy which will be responsible for this.

But still -  i'm afraid it would only fail at runtime.

Am i right ?

What are the solutions for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# doesn't have limited-length strings, the checks will have to be done at run-time. It depends on the ORM you use, though. EntityFramework has a `MaxLength` attribute you can use to decorate strings.

Comment: NHibernate also allows you to specify the maximum length of a string in your mapping configuration, but it is only used when generating a DB schema from your NHibernate mappings. As @zmbq has said, your check must be done at run-time. Though, you should also set this limitation in the database so that if something goes wrong in your program, the database won't allow the invalid string to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if` conditions to check your string length, if exceeds the required one, don't call the procedure.